# How to properly define global enum in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I cannot understand what im missing in defining enum globally.

constants.ts

```js
enum CREEP_ROLE {
  HARVESTER = 0,
  BUILDER = 1,
}
```

main.ts

```js
import './constants'

const test = CREEP_ROLE.HARVESTER;
```

Here is what typescript compiler compile this code into:

```
var CREEP_ROLE$1;
(function (CREEP_ROLE) {
    CREEP_ROLE[CREEP_ROLE["HARVESTER"] = 0] = "HARVESTER";
    CREEP_ROLE[CREEP_ROLE["BUILDER"] = 1] = "BUILDER";
})(CREEP_ROLE$1 || (CREEP_ROLE$1 = {}));
//# sourceMappingURL=constants.js.map

const test = CREEP_ROLE.HARVESTER;
```

When i run generated file, im getting `ReferenceError: CREEP_ROLE is not defined`. What i am missing?

my tslint:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "esnext",
    "lib": ["esnext"],
    "target": "es2017",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "baseUrl": "src/",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "allowUnreachableCode": false
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Export your enum:

```
export enum CREEP_ROLE {
    HARVESTER = 0,
    BUILDER = 1,
}
```

And then import like so:

```
import {CREEP_ROLE} from './constants';
```

Comment: I want it to be available globally